# GloVe anomalies with embeddings: cosine similarity for synonyms is too great

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Working with GloVe embeddings, I am receiving odd output (and consistently different from a colleague) for words that are definitely synonyms. I receive a value closer to zero than one, which seems odd, considering they are synonymous.  Wondering if there might be something I've done incorrectly?  The words are:

```py
('sycophant', 'flatterer')
```

Here is where I create my embeddings dictionary, and notice that it is a fairly high dimension vector space (300d):

```
def embedding_dictionary():
    embeddings_dict = {} # create a dictionary
    with open("glove.6b/glove.6B.300d.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f: # load the file into memory
        for line in f:
            values = line.split()
            word = values[0]
            vector = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
            embeddings_dict[word] = vector
    return embeddings_dict
```

Here is my function to compare.  Note that I am comparing two arrays, but am concerned about the output for all synonyms:

```
def compare_embeddings(array1, array2):
    similarity_scores = [] # declare a list to hold similarity score results
    for array_word1 in array1:# iterate over words in array1 in order to compare
        for array_word2 in array2: #iterate over words in array2 in order to compare
            if array_word1 in embeddings_dict and array_word2 in embeddings_dict: #find matches for both words
                similarity_scores.append((array_word1, array_word2, 1-spatial.distance.cosine
                                         (embeddings_dict[array_word1], embeddings_dict[array_word2])))
    similarity_scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

    return similarity_scores
```

visual inspection of the list of tuples indicates a very low cosine relation - while my colleague using the same approach achieved 0.650, which seems complementary to my output.

```
('sycophant', 'flatterer', 0.343303918838501)
```

Any thoughts on this?  What am I doing incorrectly?  My tokenization is standard `nltk` `word_tokenize` on a string of only words.